# ECMAScript6 AngularJS Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-filter

I am using ECMAScript6 in a project and am trying to create an Angular Filter. Below is my attempt, however I am getting the following error in the console:
Cannot set property 'PassFilter' of undefined

I am new to both ES6 and Angular.  I had to bootstrap angular that way due to legacy limitations.

```js
myAngularModule = angular.module("MyModule");

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  var myDiv = $("#myAngularDiv");
  angular.bootstrap(myDiv, ["MyModule"]);
});

myAngularModule.filter('PassFilter', APP.filters.PassFilter);



/* Filter is in a separate file: */
class PassFilter {

  constructor(input) {

    var split = input.split('');
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      result += "*";
    }
    return result;

  }
}

APP.filters.PassFilter = PassFilter;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="myAngularDiv">
  <input type="password" ng-model="password">
  <span>{{password | PassFilter}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on your comment, it seems that APP.filters is undefined.

Comment: @POZ - yes it is defined in another file, im just showing a snippet in this case of the main stuff :/

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I am saying is: could it be that your libraries are not loaded in the correct order? For instance, I would place the angular script tag at the end of my HTML (best practice with external scripts).

Comment: @POZ - so at the bottom of my page, first im loading Angular script, then my controllers and my filter.  I was more thinking maybe the input in the constructor is undefined - not sure

Comment: A constructor should never `return` anything (same as it was in ES5)!

Comment: @Bergi how would you return the result then for the filter?

Comment: I don't know Angular filters in particular, but usually you would pass a *predicate function*  to them - not a class constructor. Just use a normal `function` definition (from which `return`ing makes sense)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filter function in Angular does not take a `class` but a `filter factory function`.
This implies if you are using ES6 you can use lambda's (arrow function) to implement the filter.

```
myAngularModule.filter('PassFilter', ()=> {
   return (input)=> { 
      var split = input.split('');
      var result = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
       result += "*";
      }
      return result;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I am new in Angular.  I used class to create filter in Angular.

```
class PassFilter{
  constructor(input){
    this.input = input;
  }

  myMethod() {
    let input = this.input;

    let split = input.split('');
    let result = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      result += "*";
    }

    return result;
  }

  static PassFilterFactory(input){
    let filter = new PassFilter(input);
    return filter.myMethod();
  }
}

PassFilter.PassFilterFactory.$inject = ['input'];

angular.module('myAngularModule', [])
  .filter('passFilter', () => PassFilter.PassFilterFactory);
```

in html

```
<span>{{password | passFilter}}</span>
```

Comment: Is this in ts or es6 ?

Comment: It's not TS, it is ES-2015 (ES6)

Comment: I am not sure, but this will create a new instance of PassFilter each time that filter is called. In other words, I think that is a very ineficient way to solve this issue. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to have separate files, so:

```
// star.filter.js
export default function (input = '') {
  var split = input.split('');
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    result += "*";
  }
  return result;
}

// star.module.js
import angular from 'angular';

import starFilter from './star.filter';

let starModule = angular.module('common.star', [])
  .filter('star', () => starFilter )
  .name;

export default starModule ;
```