# How to implement custom angular 1 filter as ES6 class?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have f.e. this code:

```
function Demofilter() {
    return function(input)
    {
        return input + " Tutorial"
    }
});
app.filter('Demofilter', Demofilter);
```

How to migrate this to class (ES6 format)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript6 AngularJS Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335099/ecmascript6-angularjs-filter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.filter('Demofilter', ()=> {
   return (input)=> { 
      return input + " Tutorial"
   }
})
```

Hope that helps..Thanks